# Use zip to combine list with dataframe - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a list of dates and a dataframe with same number of records that I want to combine so that each dataframe row has a new column with the corresponding date list date.

```
final_dataset_list = []
for date, df in zip(date_list, df_dataset):
    if len(df) == 0:
        continue
    df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(date)
    final_dataset_list.append(df)
```

`df_dataset.head(5)` looks like this:

```
    time    value
0   00:00:00    70
1   00:00:03    70
2   00:00:06    71
3   00:00:09    71
4   00:00:10    71
```

`print(date_list)` looks like this:

```
['2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04', '2019-10-05', '2019-10-06', '2019-10-07', '2019-10-08', '2019-10-09', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-11', '2019-10-12', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-14', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-18', '2019-10-19', '2019-10-20', '2019-10-21', '2019-10-22', '2019-10-23', '2019-10-24', '2019-10-25', '2019-10-26', '2019-10-27', '2019-10-28', '2019-10-29', '2019-10-30', '2019-10-31']
```

I am getting following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24684/2828863862.py in <module>
      3     if len(df) == 0:
      4         continue
----> 5     df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(date)
      6     final_dataset_list.append(df)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

This seems to suggests that df_dataset is a list and not a dataframe but it is a dataframe.

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like `df_dataset` is a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(date_list[:5])  # <-- remove [:5] in production code, this is just example
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       time  value       date
0  00:00:00     70 2019-10-01
1  00:00:03     70 2019-10-02
2  00:00:06     71 2019-10-03
3  00:00:09     71 2019-10-04
4  00:00:10     71 2019-10-05
```